# Error al Conectar mi BackEnd NodeJs con MariaDB

Tags: nodejs, angular, typescript, mariadb, debian-9

Tengo una PC Virtual con Debian 9, en ella instale el node v8.16.0 y el mariadb Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.37-MariaDB . Al correr mi backend me sale este error:

> Error: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MariaDB client

Al googlearlo me indican que ejecute este comando logeado desde mysql:

```
ALTER USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mypass';
```

Y al ejecutarlo me lanza este error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'USER 'placetas'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'Ubuser55'' at line 1

Y a mi dbConfig le agregue

```
insecureAuth : true
dbConfig: {
    //connectionLimit: 10,
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'placetas',
    password: 'Ubuser55',
    database: 'placetas_database',
    insecureAuth : true
}
```

Me estoy quedando sin ideas necesito que alguien me indique el norte. Esto funciona perfectamente en Windows con mi Wampserver 2.2
Gracias de antemano.

---

Tengo estos dos ficheros que son para conectarme a MariaDB desde el BackEnd
keys.ts

```
export default {

dbConfig: {
    //connectionLimit: 10,
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'placetas',
    password: 'Ubuser55',
    database: 'placetas_database',
    insecureAuth : true
}
```

}

y el database.ts

```
    import mysql from 'promise-mysql';

    import keys from './keys';

const pool = mysql.createPool(keys.dbConfig);

pool.getConnection()
    .then(connection => {
        pool.releaseConnection(connection);
        console.log(`La conexión con ${keys.dbConfig.database} se ha realizado exitosamente!!!`);
    })
    .catch(err => {

        if (err.code === 'ENOTFOUND') {
            console.error(`Nombre incorrecto del Servidor de la Base de Datos ${keys.dbConfig.database}.`);
        }
        if (err.code === 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR') {
            console.error(`Usuario o Contraseña de la Base de Datos ${keys.dbConfig.database} incorrectos.`);
        }
        if (err.code === 'ER_BAD_DB_ERROR') {
            console.error(`Nombre de la Base de Datos ${keys.dbConfig.database} incorrecto.`);
        }
        if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
            console.error(`Se ha cerrado la conexión con la Base de Datos ${keys.dbConfig.database}.`);
        }
        if (err.code === 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR') {
            console.error(`La Base de Datos ${keys.dbConfig.database} posee muchas conexiones.`);
        }
        if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
            console.error(`La conexión a la Base de Datos ${keys.dbConfig.database} ha sido rechazada.`);
        }
        // Temporal 
        console.log(err);
    });

export default pool;
```

Comment: Enseña lo que estas intentando, pon el codigo que provoca tu error, si no no te podran ayudar. Pero por lo que pones dice que tienes un error en la sintaxis `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

Comment: El error me lo da cuando pongo este comando logeado en mysql ALTER USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'mypass';

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve ese problema con mysql y php (aunque aquí es mariaDB):

Con MySQL 8 hay problemas de conexión entre php y mysql
Esto se debe a que en mysql 8 cambiaron la codificación default a **utfmb4**
Para solucionarlo hay que cambie la codificación de **mysql a utf8**.
Para lograrlo hay que editar el archivo C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini
Agregar:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
character-set-server = utf8
```

Editar:

```
default_authentication_plugin = mysql_native_password
```

Si aun no funciona debido al metodo de autenticacion, hay que crear el usuario.Esto funciona aunque el usuario ya exista con caching_sha2_password:

```
CREATE USER 'usuario'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Eso fue lo que yo hice, espero te sirva aunque se que es para mariaDB el error se ve muy similar a lo que me salia.

Comment: en debian9 en que lugar se encuentra este fichero???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482234/how-do-i-find-the-mysql-my-cnf-location

Comment: El problema es que creo que mariadb no soporta mysql_native_password porque ek error de sinstxis que me da es que no lo reconoce

Comment: orale, ese si es un problema

Answer (score 0):

Al fin lo consegui. El que persevera triunfa...

Lo que hice fue desinstalara todo el MariaDB y comenzar de cero.

Una vez instalado le asigne una contraseña de root de forma manual. De esa forma me  carga el plugin por defecto (mysql_native_password) que es el que necesito.

Utilize un paso a paso de Chacho Cool net, muy bueno, lo recomiendo.

[Cómo Instalar MariaDB en Debian 9](https://chachocool.com/como-instalar-mariadb-en-debian-9/)